# On keydown in Ada

Tags: ada

I would need to execute some function when the user presses the "escape" key in my Ada program. I know we can retrieve what he enters thanks to get_line but it's not exactly what I need to do.
Indeed, I don't want to stop the program until he enters "escape".

First, is it possible ?

Comment: Everything's possible. What have you tried so far? Provide code.

Comment: As I said, I tried the get_line instruction but it stops my program until the user enters something. This is not what I need to do. I would like to run my program normally and when the user enters the "escape" it does something. I'm used to javascript and I'd need to do something equivalent to the "onkeydown"

Comment: On *nix systems, the more conventional way would be to implement this with a SIGINT handler.

Comment: @flyx The escape key won't cause SIGINT to be signalled (usually it's Control-C that does that).  It may be possible to set things up so that a key input will cause SIGIO or SIGPOLL to be signalled, but my experience has been that doing so is difficult, possibly unreliable, and not portable.

Comment: @user2302725 `onkeydown` is more a function of browsers, not part of the JavaScript language.  It's the browser that takes care of noticing when keys are pressed and released, and it causes the callbacks in the JavaScript program.  If you're running your Ada program in conjunction with some kind of GUI library, it probably supports similar features in some other way; I believe GTKAda has this functionality, for instance.  If you're running on a console, you'll have to do something different.

Comment: @ajb: Yes, listening for `Ctrl-C` instead of escape was part of my suggestion.

Comment: What about Ada.Text_IO.Get_Immediate ?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get the characters without the need to press enter using :

```
Ada.Text_IO.Get_Immediate (Answer)
```

with `Answer`, a `Character`.

And the escape key is ASCII 27, so you can check whether `Character'Pos(Answer)` equals 27 or not. Also, as suggested in the comments, you can also compare `Answer` to `Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC`.

Here is an example of a program that display "Yeah!!!1!!1!" in a loop until the key ESC is pressed.

```
with Ada.Characters.Latin_1;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is
    Finished : Boolean := False;

    task Escape_Task;

    task body Escape_Task is
        Answer : Character;
    begin
        loop
            Ada.Text_IO.Get_Immediate(Answer);
            if Answer = Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC then
                Finished := True;
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end Escape_Task;

begin
    while not finished loop
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Yeahh!!!1!!1!");
    end loop;
end Test;
```

Comment: It stops my program until I enter something, it's not what I want to do. I would need to do the equivalent to "onkeydown" of javascript.

Comment: I totally forgot the ada threads, I'm going to work with that thanks ;)

Comment: Or just use Get_Immediate(Answer, Available). If Available is False, no key was pressed. If Available is True, Answer contains the key that was pressed.

Comment: Better to use [Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-3-3.html), or the obsolete [ASCII.ESC](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-J-5.html), rather than `Character'Pos (27)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: :blush: